# IIS Redirect URL with subdomain to domain only

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I had previously setup a virtual directory to be accessible via `https://example.com/MyWebsite`, but now I need the website to be accessible via `https://example.com` only.

I tried HTTP Redirect and set the redirect requests to `https://example.com`. When I access `https://example.com/MyWebsite` via my browser, the page cannot be loaded. Accessing `https://example.com` only show a blank IIS page. Which I assume it's redirecting to the default IIS page instead of loading any website.

I also tried URL rewrite, I tried creating an inbound rule to redirect `https://example.com` to `https://example.com/MyWebsite`. In the browser, it shows blank IIS page as well, instead of redirect to my website.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Add "https://example.com" in the binding and check

Comment: Maybe caching problem also, try to clear the cache of browser and check.